# FullCalendar: show reversed list views

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I reverse the events in the list views, so that the event with the most futuristic date appears at the beginning (top)?

Comment: There's no built-in option for this, so you could either modify the fullCalendar source code to do what you want, or create your own custom view (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/, not a quick task). Failing that you could probably make it as a feature request to the maintainer, via GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

@F.Mora your solution is almost perfect but in our case we add some custom classNames and have multiple items under each headline.

Here is our enhanced version :

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
    var renderedEvents = $('.fc-list-table  tr');
    var reorderedEvents = [];
    var blockEvents = null;
    renderedEvents.map(function(key, event) {
        if ($(event).hasClass('fc-list-heading')) {
            if (blockEvents) {
                reorderedEvents.unshift(blockEvents.children());   
            }
            blockEvents = $('<tbody></tbody>');
        }
        blockEvents.append(event);
    });
    reorderedEvents.unshift(blockEvents.children());
    $('.fc-list-table tbody').html(reorderedEvents);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@CarComp,

As ADyson commented in the comment to the OP, your best bet if you want do not want to deal with the dom after the html has been rendered is to download the source and make the modification there in the ListView renderSegList function.

Reverse the order of iteration through the list that it is being created and then you will have what you are looking for.

[image]

This will, of course, apply to all ListView implementations of the calendar.  There would need to be an option added to toggle back and forth, which would be a bit more involved.

Comment: I did open a ticket on GitHub and turns out it's a pretty popular request.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for this, inverted event lists using jquery:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
    var eventosRendered = $('#timeline tr');
    var eventosInversa = [];
    var headingPendiente = null;
    eventosRendered.map(function(key, evento) {
        switch(evento.className) {
            case 'fc-list-heading':
                if (headingPendiente) {
                    eventosInversa.unshift(headingPendiente);
                }
                headingPendiente = evento;
                break;
            case 'fc-list-item':
                eventosInversa.unshift(evento);
                break;
        }
    });
    eventosInversa.unshift(headingPendiente);

    $('#timeline tbody').append(eventosInversa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the version I use (fullCalendar v4):

```
datesRender: function(info) {
    var list = $(info.el).find('.fc-list-table tbody');
    list.find('.fc-list-heading').each((i,heading) => {
      var children = $(heading).nextUntil('.fc-list-heading')
      list.prepend(children)
      list.prepend(heading)
    })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this for fullCalendar v5. It´s based on @Yo1 answer

```
    eventsSet: function(dateInfo){
      var renderedEvents = $('.fc-list-table  tr');
      var reorderedEvents = [];
      var blockEvents = null;
      renderedEvents.map(function(key, event) {
        if ($(event).hasClass('fc-list-day')) {
          if (blockEvents) {
            reorderedEvents.unshift(blockEvents.children());
          }
          blockEvents = $('<tbody></tbody>');
        }
        blockEvents.append(event);
      });
      if (blockEvents){
        reorderedEvents.unshift(blockEvents.children());
        $('.fc-list-table tbody').html(reorderedEvents);
      }
    },
```

Comment: Could you give full code or demo. I don't understand where to insert your pasage in whole code of js.

Comment: Insert your code where you are initializing the calendar. Read the documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc

Comment: In fullcalendar-5.10.0 the cod gives an error in renderedEvents.map function.

Comment: You are assigning blockEvents outside of the if statement in the .map